# C# query with dynamic tablename

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to build a query where the tablename will be dynamic and I will get it from another query. The 2 queries are in different datacontexts.

**CODE**

```
var tablename = (from tab in db.Tabs
                 where tab.id == tabid
                 select tab.name).FirstOrDefault();

var pid = (from p in tablename
           select p.id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: In that case you have to write your SQL statements on yourself. But you should use `SqlCommand` class and its `Parameters` property to avoid injection attacks.

Comment: @Oliver How can I do that?

Comment: In the second query, what you are doing is to query a string, not the table itself. Obviously, that will not yield the result you want. If you write your own sql statement, note that you can't parameterize identifiers in sql, so you will have to either create the query text in your c# code (with a minimized risk of sql injection, since you are not involving user intput here), or create a stored procedure that uses dynamic sql inside (where you have a better chance of defending your self from sql injection attacks).

Answer (score -6, accepted):

```
using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader sqlReader;

    com.CommandText = "Select id from @tableName";
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", tableName);

    com.Connection = sqlCon;
    sqlCon.Open();
    sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader();

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(sqlReader); //Query output is in dt now
}
```

Comment: This code not works! You can not pass the table name as parameter.

Comment: passing table name as a parameter will throw InvalidOperationException in this case

Answer (score 3):

Table names cannot be supplied as parameters, so you'll have to construct the SQL string manually in either a function or stored procedure before you can execute it.

```
    create PROC read_from_dynamic_table(@TableName NVARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @SQLSelectQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
SET @SQLSelectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName

  exec(@SQLSelectQuery)
END
```

Then you can call the proc to with table name as parameter

Comment: Can you provide the whole query ? The second one in my op

Comment: Be really careful: If `@TableName` comes from user input, it is not sanitized.  Though you are using a variable, you are using it to generate a new query in `@SQLSelectQuery` unsanitized.

Answer (score 0):

To feed table name dynamically into the 2nd query, you can use stored procedure instead of LINQ.

When you got your stored procedure, you then call it by passing `tablename` (the result from your first query.

SP doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure

This is an rough example just to give you an idea:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProc
   @tablename varchar(100)
  AS
  begin 
   select * from @tablename  
 end
```

Comment: I dont want to do it with SP. Is it possible to do it with code?

Comment: uhm.. I'm not aware of any other ways, sorry

Comment: `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( " select * from " + tablename);` - don't forget about SQL injection

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in sql.