# SQLite command.Parameters.Add() not working

Tags: c#, sqlite

Here's my code.

```
public void setUpdate(List<string> code, string tableName)
{
            SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connection);
            SQLiteCommand UPDATE = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE @TableName SET @ColumnName = @Value WHERE Key = @PK", con);
            UPDATE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", "TEST");
            UPDATE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName", code[1]);
            UPDATE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", code[2]);
            UPDATE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PK", code[0]);
            using (con)
            {
                con.Open();
                UPDATE.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
}
```

And I'm getting this exception

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
near "@TableName": syntax error'
```

I already tried using

```
UPDATE.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@TableName", DbType.String) .Value = tableName);
```

Still getting the same exception.

I don't know anymore how to solve this.
I don't wanna use the concatenation because it screws up the query when you pass a value like the one below.

```
Smith's
```

EDIT:

I placed a breakpoint on

```
using (con)
```

Then checked the commandText. The result is:

```
"UPDATE @TableName SET @ColumnName = @Value WHERE Key = @PK"
```

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, you can not parameterize as you are attempting by providing the table and column.  You have to build those parts as direct part of  the command.  You can obviously add  the parameters for the set value and where though.  If building the query by adding string parts together BE CAREFUL OF SQL INJECTION.

Comment: I already tried it. It gives me the same error but on @value.

Comment: I don't think you can parameterize either table names or column names in a command object.

Comment: I tried hard coding the Table Name and Column Names still same error :( .

Answer (score 0):

I think there is the problem with table name as a parameter.
So firstly try to left all parameters except of table name (hardcode 'TEST' into query temporarily) and if it works take a look on this:
[C# query with dynamic tablename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765395/c-sharp-query-with-dynamic-tablename)

Comment: Updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Again, trying to build a query with from and column names you can't do as PARAMETER.  They need to be fixed in the string.  BUT CAUTION.  DO NOT Allow the table/column/etc parts that you build come from an untrusted source, especially the web for damage of SQL-Injection.

If your system is controlling the origin AND QUALIFIED, or otherwise internally control the table name being passed in, AND you control / qualify the column name being passed in, I would adjust your function as follows:

```
public void setUpdate(List<string> code, string tableName)
{
   SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connection);
   SQLiteCommand UPDATE = new SQLiteCommand(
"UPDATE " + tableName + " set " + code[1] + " = @Value WHERE Key = @PK", con);

   UPDATE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", code[2]);
   UPDATE.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PK", code[0]);
   using (con)
   {
      con.Open();
      UPDATE.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
   }
}
```

Again, this is on the premise that YOU are controlling and sanitizing the origins of the tableName parameter, and your code array, second element via [1] representing the column name.  The setting value EQUAL TO and where key EQUALS are ok for parameters.
And if that does not work, I would start with a query that you know is legit/clear just to TEST the functionality with parameters.

```
"UPDATE YourTable set YourColumn = @Value WHERE Key = @PK"
```